# How do I manage lots of example codes from a textbook in a single project?

Tags: c, include

I am studying C with a textbook, and it has of course a lot of example source code for me to practice.

I had no problem with managing these code files when I was just studying with gcc, a text editor and terminal.

And now I wanted to use an IDE so I can get hints before compiling each source code, so downloaded one and trying to put every code file into a single project template the IDE offers.

The code files are usually short, and always have main function for each, so creating a project and importing all of them prevented me from compiling: I have multiple main function which I should have not.

Here is an example so I can describe what the problem I have:

I now started 7th chapter in the book, so I created a project named 'ch7'. And I have currently two example codes. The project can't be compiled with all the codes at once, so I commented every main function in each of the examples and made a new main.c, containing the main function part from the examples.

example code 1 (find.c) - has 6 functions, including 1 main function (I made it so it's now in comment block)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int NUM_ADS = 7;
char *ADS[] = { ... };    
int sports_no_bieber(char* s) { ... }
int sports_or_workout(char* s) { ... }
int ns_theater(char* s) { ... }
int arts_theater_or_dining(char* s) { ... }
void find(int (match)(char*) ) { ... }
/* int main() { ... } */
```

example code 2 (test_drive.c) - has 7 functions and 1 structure, including 1 main function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int compare_scores(const void* score_a, const void* score_b) { ... }
int compare_scores_desc(const void* score_a, const void* score_b) { ... }
typedef struct { ... } rectangle;
int compare_areas(const void* rect_a, const void* rect_b) { ... }
int compare_names(const void* name_a, const void* name_b) { ... }
int compare_areas_desc(const void* rect_a, const void* rect_b) { ... }
int compare_names_desc(const void* name_a, const void* name_b) { ... }
/* int main() { ... } */
```

I commented the main function for each codes because I wanted to use them in a new main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "find.c"
#include "test_drive.c"
// this list will grow as I make more example codes and include them like this.
// And yes, I know this part brings problem. I shouldn't directly include code files like this.

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    /*
    statements for main function in example code 1;
    */

    statements for main function in example code 2;
    // this part is uncommented, because I am testing this one.

    /*
    statements for other example codes will be here after...
    */
    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

This of course returned compile errors: multiple definition of the functions.

I know I can make a header and put function declarations for every function existing in all the example codes, and then include that header to my new main.c.

But is this the only way to manage all example codes in a single project in an IDE? The files I've shown here is only two, but a header for them should have 11 function declarations. And I have lot more example codes, from chapter 1 to 6, including about 30 c files (and much more total amount of functions in each c file of course), some h, csv and txt files for specific example source codes.

If I have to make a header for all of them, it wouldn't be only consuming lots of time but also will force me to add another few lines to the header every time I write a new code as I keep studying.

It seems much ineffective compared with just writing a code file in a text editor, opening terminal and calling gcc to compile it.

So I think there should be much effective way to manage such example code files in a single place, which shouldn't only be a 'project'. I want to find a way in which I can get advantages of using IDE while code file management doesn't go too complicated.

Comment: If you are using e.g. Visual Studio you can have a single workspace with multiple projects. Put each example in its own project, and make sure that each project get its own directory on the disk. That way you separate the different examples on the disk as well as in the VS workspace.

Comment: Would it be okay to make a project only for a single example code? Currently I separated example codes by the chapter it appears, so directory 'ch1' has some codes and compiled results, and 'ch2', 'ch3', ... goes for same manner. It is convenient if I am to use only text editors to access them.

Comment: I didn't described exactly what programs I uses because I thought if I do the answer will be dependent to that specific program and environment. I just installed NetBeans, and it has a function, 'Project Groups', looks similar to VS's workspace.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove Main from all the files.
2. Create another files for Main.
3. Segregate all the files and implement everything in a procedure/function as you wanted.
4. In your Main file include only those file which you need and do the operation as you wanted.

As you go further in chapter try to keep the logic in particular procedure/ function such that you can again reuse it in the Main file.

Since it is really high level, i am assuming you are going through the chapters and trying the examples.

Comment: I want to ask more about last 3 steps. Create another file's' for main? Then do I have two files for every example? Segregate from where, and did that implementing everything means, as an example, moving all codes from find.c and test_drive.c into a single file (or header so I can include it from a new file for main)?

Comment: No u need to have only one main file. Let's take an example.
1. Say, you have Find.C file and Sort.C file.
2. Both the file will have logic defined like find logic will be in Find.c and Sort will be in Sort.C.
3. In main file you just need to call those routines by including the files in header.
So, this is called segregating the logic. Hope this helps.
Please vote if you like the answer. Thanks

Comment: 3 <- Do you mean I call those routines by like `#include "Find.c"` in the head of the main file? Or do I have to make an header and include c files in there, and then include the header in the main file? Need more description about 'calling a routine' I think.